# Replacing children with parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables

Groups

| Area Number | District |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | EW |
| 1 | QQ |
| 2 | RE |
| 2 | NM |

Locations

| ID | District | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ER |  |
| 2 | LQ |  |
| 3 | QQ | 1 |
| 4 | EW | 1 |
| 5 | WQ | 1 |
| 6 | NM | 2 |
| 7 | RE | 2 |

What I am trying to do is output a list where if all the districts for a particular ID in the Groups Table are listed in all the Districts for that particular parent, then remove all the associated rows in Groups and replace it with it's parent

For Area 1, this would just output the same rows in groups because area 1 covers EW, QQ but not WQ
However for Area 2, Both NM and RE match all the districts under its parent hence I want to replace the last two rows in the groups table with Area 2, District LQ

Is it possible to do this in a single statement without resorting to cte's, temporary tables etc?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Please add your best not working attempt, for this is no code platform.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.